# C# Using .Min() on a Dictionary, min value, but return a key?

Tags: c#

I'm not sure if this is even possible, as far as I can tell, it isn't, but I have a dictionary and I want to find the Min() of values, but return either the KVP or Key. Currently I am using orderby, but I feel like that is going to be super inefficient once this grows large enough.

Comment: Perhaps you could wrap your dictionary in a class with an Add method.  When you call the Add method keep track of the value being added and save it if it is the min.

Comment: @Sam Then what do you do when that value is removed?

Comment: I think @Sam has a great idea, you can easily check if it is removed.

Comment: @JimW But then what should the new value be if it's removed?

Comment: @Servy find the new min.

Comment: @Sam Then you're back to doing linear searches, you're just caching the value.

Comment: @Servy but only if and when you remove.

Comment: The alternative is to iterate, so you're better off caching.

Comment: @Sam Which you may well end up doing more often than you need the key of the minimum value.

Comment: @Servy, no you could just invalidate the cache until the next request for the min.  You can have the best of both worlds.

Comment: @JimW Then you're not keeping track of the minimum value as items are added.  If you just want to memoize the `Min` query, do that, and don't relate it to the data structure at all.

Comment: Actually OP would do well to be more specific with his requirement.  There are many different ways to accomplish this goal.

Comment: @Servy we're about to get moved to chat - but you are correct - I suppose it depends on the expected usage but it seems a cheap way to win for specific expected usages.

Comment: @JimW And a good way to see massive slowdowns for any usages that don't fall in line with a very narrow situation.  If you know for a fact that you're in a very specific situation, then sure.  We don't know if the OP is in said situation.

Comment: @Servy I don't agree you get any slowdown. If you're just invalidating the cache when an item is removed, and resetting the cache next time Min is called.  Until you call Remove, you enjoy the cache, and then suffer no cache until Min is called next.  So Min is fast until Remove is called, then only as slow as if you were just iterating all items anyway.  So no loss.  If Min is called and then Add, you're still ahead.

Comment: @JimW Then you're not getting any *benefits* of doing that unless you call `Min`, then add items, then call `Min` again, and so on.  if you're manipulating the data and getting the `Min`, or every removing a value in between calls, you're gaining nothing and adding a decent bit of overhead of all of the state checking all throughout your mutation code.  The only situation in which you come out ahead is rather narrow.

Comment: @Jim you only invalidate if min is removed. OP needs to be more specific.

Comment: You guys are overcomplicating this a lot, but I appreciate it, very interesting read. The min is only needed once every few iterations, and generated on the spot in a dataset that is discarded, so writing an entire class and then optimizing that class is far more than necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) and its `MinBy` method:

```
var pair = dictionary.MinBy(x => x.Value);
var key = pair.Key;
```

(And yes, this is O(N) rather than O(N log N) - more efficient than ordering. It won't need as much memory, either.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there are any shortcuts and I would think that iterating every item looking for the min would be faster than sorting it first.  You could easily compare speeds to find out for sure.

-EDIT: After the comment-

If you use MoreLinq.MinBy, your code will be more concise, but you won't avoid iterating every element.

https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs

So, to answer your question more explicitly, you are best to iterate every element looking for the lowest value, and when you have finished iterating all elements, return the key.

I offer this answer in case you don't want to bring in MoreLinq for any reason.